# How to append a Linux command line to file?

Tags: bash, here-document

I am writing a bash script which will generate a Vagrantfile. The reason that i use a bash script to generate Vagrantfile is to enable my colleague to use a single script in setting up their environments before running `vagrant up`
The challenge that I facing now is when appending command line to the Vagrantfile, the command is executed instead of appended into Vagrantfile

For example (`setup-vagrant-host.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.
.
some pre requisites steps
.
.
.
# Generate Vagrantfile
cat <<EOL > Vagrantfile
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.define "vagrant-host"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        sudo su
        apt update
        ipaddress=`hostname -I | awk '{print $2}'`
        echo "*** IP address is $ipaddress ***"
    SHELL
    end
EOL
vagrant up
```

When i execute the above script, `hostname -I | awk '{print $2}'` always executed instead of appended to Vagrantfile, I dont know am I doing this right, please suggest a better way...

*Not native english speaker, forget my poor grammar, thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expansions in the here-document are carried out by the shell unless the expansions themselves are quoted, or the here-document itself is quoted.

To quote the command substitution and the various other variables that the shell would try to expand in the here-document in your example:

```bsh
cat <<EOL > Vagrantfile
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.define "vagrant-host"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        sudo su
        apt update
        ipaddress=\\\$(hostname -I | awk '{print \\\$2}')
        echo "*** IP address is \\\$ipaddress ***"
    SHELL
    end
EOL
```

Note that we have to quote not only the `$` in the command substitution, but also in `$2` in the `awk` code and in `$ipaddress` in the `echo` invocation.  We actually need to doubly quote these strings using `\\\` since they are actually part of an embedded here-document (`SHELL`).  each `\\\$` would be replaced by `\$` when `Vagrantfile` is written.

Unless you really *want* the shell to expand some variable in the here-document, it is usually easier to just quote the here-document as a whole.  This is done by quoting the initial here-document delimiter string:

```bsh
cat <<'EOL' > Vagrantfile
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.define "vagrant-host"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-'SHELL'
        sudo su
        apt update
        ipaddress=`hostname -I | awk '{print $2}'`
        echo "*** IP address is $ipaddress ***"
    SHELL
    end
EOL
```

Here I've opted for quoting both the embedded here-document and the outer here-document.

Depending on how this code is used and where, you may want to make sure that both the first and the embedded here-documents are indented with tabs and that both here-documents are started with `<<-` (`<<-'EOL'` and `<<-'START'`).  This would ensure that the embedded here-document could be correctly parsed (the ending `SHELL` needs to be first on the line once `Vagrantfile` has been created).

Note that I have not commented on the *contents* of the here-document in terms of what it tries to achieve.  I don't know whether `sudo su` makes sense or not, for example.

Comment: Appreciate your clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the backticks in your heredoc with backslashes:

```
        ipaddress=\`hostname -I | awk '{print $2}'\`
```

Comment: As discussed eg. (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts] the `$()` syntax is generally considered preferable to backticks, therefore
`ipaddress=\$(hostname -I | awk '{print $2}')` would be a (superior) alternative

Comment: Note that that part of the code happens to be located inside an embedded here-document, in the here-document.

Comment: But the embedded here-doc is not Shell but Ruby.
Therefore the double escapes should be futile.